# Creating a user interface that talks from a server ( maybe localhost ) and can be installed in any PC( windows ) using java and net-beans?

Tags: java, php, mysql, jakarta-ee

i have built a web application that runs on browser, using `PHP, jS, HTML, Mysql`. Its a Warehouse Manager for a construction company, its works fine and they (the users) are loving it. But when its come to install a fresh copy in a different system in the network, its very hard for a normal non technical user.

So, i was thinking to work on a new Warehouse manager that can be installed on any system in the network or can be connected via online server by logging in. So the user just have to click some next buttons to install and then they can use it.

The question is, what are the available languages, servers and frameworks are available in open source licence and what would be best for me as i know `php, java core and gui, c, can handle apache, mysql for database.`

And what should i read? refer some good books, blogs, articles that can be useful.

thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is open source installer software?  If so, check out Inno Setup at http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php.  This allows you to run 3rd party installers and write configuration routines etc.

Comment: no man, i want to know how to build a GUI in java that communicate with server. and what tools will be needed..

Comment: I would suggest you to build a web application that runs on a centralized (or foreign) server. You can use PHP or Ruby (because they may have less cost to mantain the server) or Java. I wouldn't suggest you to build a native application, and if you do so Java & C# are both good ways because runs in VM. But since your app already run on browser, i will suggest to make a webapp in PHP, Java, Ruby or any language supporting well webapps, and then the UI is just simply html, css e js. Going to stand-alone and code UI, java and Swing may be cool for you.

Comment: its true that a centralized sever would be best but what if i want it to be sold on market. That any company can buy and install it in a pc and then via wifi or in lan all the user can use it. the only problem is the one time setup of the server, db, and application is very complicated and configuration of ini files can be a headache for non tech users. is there a way to create a combined installer for apache, mysql, php, and coping other files and configurations ??

Comment: You always need a running server and it has to be configured. Php, usually doesn't require much effort. You distribute the sources and then the installer just goes in htdocs of the targeting server. Minimal configurations of a file is required. If you want an executable (and there at first launch or during install you ask for configuration) just go for java, c# or even c++.